# Are there any softwares or commands that allows me to bring up a list of external commands

Tags: command-line

My title may be confusing but an example might help what I am trying to ask. For example:

I installed a Resource monitor called bpytop from https://github.com/aristocratos/bpytop. Now if I open my terminal and type the command `bpytop` the program comes up. Good right? Now I go ahead and install y-ppa-manager, and other programs that we type in the terminal to open up.

Now a few days/weeks/months go by and I can't remember the command to bring up `bpytop`, or I want to see all the commands that I can type into my terminal that will execute programs via terminal.

Are there any programs or commands that can save all the external terminal commands like this?

Answer (score 1):

Unlike the rest of these answers, mine is pretty easy.

I keep a handy text document that has snippets of code, commands for installed applications - or at least how to start them, and things of that nature.

Then, beyond all that, I use the [alias function](https://www.howtogeek.com/439736/how-to-create-aliases-and-shell-functions-on-linux/) for many things. I use aliases to make the commands something that I will be more likely to remember, or at least guess.

For example:

```
alias update="sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt clean -y"
```

So, when I want to update, I just type 'update' into the terminal and it does all of those processes for me without any additional oversight.

Next, and probably the most important, is that I use these aliases across multiple installs and even with entirely different OSes. If I'm using zypper, then I have the same command but a different backend by way of alias. I don't have to remember all the various commands because I remember the aliases.

I also keep my handy text document, helpfully called `linuxterminalnotes.txt` and share it with the other computers I own. It doesn't require a high-tech solution, it requires a network connection or a USB thumbdrive.

The only effort required is to update it. If I install something new that requires a cryptic terminal entry, I save it to the file. I keep this file, and my various alias files, backed up across multiple devices and in multiple locations. The only tech I need is a simple text editor.

Comment: I agree with this one the most...except I probably would agree if there is a gripe against it for easy access on multiple computers... I use what used to be known as a notebook, but that's just me... electronically, I just bookmark the related web pages in the browser with a meaningful title... and then organize the bookmarks into topics. I guess something like google drive would be smarter...

Comment: Thumb drive and plenty of web hosting are my solutions. I use password enabled compressed files to upload them, as they do contain sensitive data - but not truly dangerous data. I don't store my passwords with them, for example. As text files, they compress nicely.

Answer (score 0):

If you can remember (or guess) the first few letters of the command, then you can use the bash shell's `compgen` builtin to generate possible *command completions* ex.

```
compgen -A command bp
```

If you can't remember anything about the command, then `compgen -A command` or equivalently `compgen -c` will give you an exhaustive list of all available commands - but it may be too long to be useful (you could pipe the result to `less` to make it easier to page through).

Note that `command` in this context includes shell builtins, aliases, functions, and keywords. You could exclude these as follows:

```
comm -23 <(compgen -c | sort) <({ compgen -abk ; compgen -A function; } | sort) | less
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no command as such that lists all external executables. However, the tool `dmenu` comes with a small script that collects all executables in the list. It is called `dmenu_path` and has following contents:

```
#!/bin/sh

cachedir="${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-"$HOME/.cache"}"
cache="$cachedir/dmenu_run"

[ ! -e "$cachedir" ] && mkdir -p "$cachedir"

IFS=:
if stest -dqr -n "$cache" $PATH; then
    stest -flx $PATH | sort -u | tee "$cache"
else
    cat "$cache"
fi
```

You could either install `dmenu` or just copy/modify this script in your own script `listexecs` to have a command listing all executables.

Probably the easiest way to find your command would just be to run `dmenu_run`. That displays that list in the dmenu menu system. You can type a few letters to narrow the list down, and thus find the name of the command you are looking for using the search capabilities of dmenu. Press <kbd>esc</kbd> when done. <kbd>Enter</kbd> would run the application.